# Python Join two rows and create csv with new row

Tags: python, csv, row, concatenation

```
#!c:/users/jon/python
#Python 2.7.6

import csv
from string import maketrans

intab = "()-/"
outtab = "    "
tab0 = maketrans(intab, outtab)

plist1 = []
x1 = ''

with open('o:/p1.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    csvfile1 = csv.reader(f1)
    next(f1)
    for row in csvfile1:

        row[0] = row[0].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        row[1] = row[1].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        x1 = row[0] + '-' + row[1]

        plist1.append(x1)
f1.close()

print str(x1)
#   prints correctly:
#   AAA1111111-BBB2222222

newcsv1 = csv.writer(open('newcsv1.csv', 'wb'))
for row in plist1:
    newcsv1.writerow(row)

#   creates a csv file that looks like below:
#   A,A,A,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-,B,B,B,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

i hope someone can point me in the right direction...

i would like to create a variable which will concatenate row[0] and row[1] with a '-' in between and create a new csv file that only contains the new variable.

the csv file i am working with looks like below:

```
phone#1,phone#2,phone#3,phone#4
(AAA)111/1111,(BBB)222-2222,(CCC)333/3333,(DDD)444-4444
```

i would like the new csv file to contain only one cell/value as below:

```
AAA1111111-BBB2222222
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newcsv1 = csv.writer(open('newcsv1.csv', 'wb'))
for row in plist1:
    newcsv1.writerow([row]) # put row inside a list
```

`writerow` expects an iterable so iterating over `plist1` row is a string which `writer` iterates over and splits into single chars when writing to the file.

If plist is a list with a single element just use :

```
newcsv1.writerow(plist1)
```

This will write `AAA1111111-BBB2222222` to your file.

Using your code:

```
with open("newcsv1.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    csvfile1 = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvfile1:
        print row
        row[0] = row[0].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        row[1] = row[1].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        x1 = row[0] + '-' + row[1]
        row[2] = row[2].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        row[3] = row[3].translate(tab0).replace(' ','')
        x2 = row[2] + '-' + row[3]
        plist1.append([x1]) # append inside a list
        plist1.append([x2])
newcsv1 = csv.writer(open('newcsv1.csv', 'wb'))
newcsv1.writerows(plist1) # write all rows from the list
```

Comment: could i add more values to plist1? say i wanted the new csv file to contain the value of row[0]-row[1] and additional rows? like row[5], row[8] and row [10].. in other words could i "append" more values to plist1?

Comment: yes, just make sure you either append each inside a list or wrap each one in a list when iterating over plist

Comment: how can i append each row inside a list?

Comment: `plist1.append([x1])`

Comment: would this be the most effective way to append more rows? `x1 = x1 + ',' + row[2] + ',' + row[3]` can i convert [x1] to string to avoid printing the single quote and brackets?

Comment: do you want to get all `(AAA)111/1111,(BBB)222-2222,(CCC)333/3333,(DDD)444-4444`?

Comment: in a csv file, yes. so `AAA1111111-BBB222222,CCC3333333,DDD4444444`

Comment: I will add to my answer in a few minutes

Comment: can you view the summary of the edit i did to your code?

Comment: @jes516, I cannot see any edit. Is there some problem with the code?

Comment: your code works, it wrote the values with `['  ']`. i modded your code to remove the `['  ']` but then it wrote all the values(rows) to one cell. how would i go about printing the values(rows) without the `['  ']` and each value(row) in their own individual cells?

Comment: it does not write the rows with `['  ']` for me, I am not sure I understand you

Comment: i apologize, you are correct it does not print with `['  ']`. is it possible to print the values(rows) in the same line?

Comment: what are  `values(rows)` and why are you worried about printing?

Comment: write is what i meant by print. so when i open the `newcsv1.csv` file i would like cell A1 = `row[0]-row[1]`, cell B1 = `CCC3333333`, cell C1 = `DDD4444444`. i meant value as in each row[?]. to summarize, sometimes i need to concatenate columns within the csv file and extract specific columns (from same csv file). most of the time i do not need all the data in the original csv file and that is what i am trying to learn/accomplish with py..

Comment: just write them all to a single row or there is a dictWriter that will write the headers for you and give you separate columns

Comment: thanks for your help. just wondering if you could further explain some things in py for me. maybe i can email you or send you a message on here (is that possible?) thanks -jon-

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made some complex code from a simple problem. Here's what I would do, based on the problem, and not your code:

```
from string import maketrans

tab = maketrans("()-/", "    ")
with open("o:/p1.csv", "rb") as fi:
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as fo:
        fi.readline() # skip first line
        for line in fi:
            line = line.translate(tab).replace(" ", "")
            newvals = line.split(",")
            newrow = newvals[0] + '-' + newvals[1] + '\n'
            fo.write(newrow)
```

I am not familiar with the csvfile module, so there could be some improvement there, but I think your code should be as simple as this, if not simpler.

Comment: I am curious about the downvote, considering that the code solves his problem, it is straightforward and I did note my lack of knowledge of the CSV module. Maybe with a bit of feedback I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Padraic's answer -- your are passing a string which is also an iterable.  See this:

```
>>> s = "abcd"
>>> for i in s:
...   print i,
... 
a b c d
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overthinking it. A CSV is just like any other file, so this will work:

```
with open('newcsv1.csv', 'w') as newcsv1:
    newcsv1.write(str(x1) + '\n')
```